# How to launch the application after getting install location from registry

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, registry

I wanted too find out how to launch an application after getting the install location from the registry using 
string appLocation = (string) rkSubKey.GetValue("InstallLocation"); 
Now that i have the installed application location how do i launch it to open.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
[System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2) as:

```
Process.Start("myApplicationPath");
```

Comment: Hello, thanks it did launch the application but it didnt open up the file project  that was meant to open up when the application is launched